# Convert code behind arguments into mvvm xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

got a question on how to convert this code behind into a mvvm style, Here's a sample

```cs
void CameraView_MediaCaptured(object sender, MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (cameraView.CaptureMode)
    {
        default:
        case CameraCaptureMode.Default:
        case CameraCaptureMode.Photo:
            previewVideo.IsVisible = false;
            previewPicture.IsVisible = true;
            previewPicture.Rotation = e.Rotation;
            previewPicture.Source = e.Image;
            doCameraThings.Text = "Snap Picture";
            break;
        case CameraCaptureMode.Video:
            previewPicture.IsVisible = false;
            previewVideo.IsVisible = true;
            previewVideo.Source = e.Video;
            doCameraThings.Text = "Start Recording";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "MVVM style" but you could use EventToCommand behavior from the Xamarin Community Toolkit, or you could just create public methods on your VM and call those from the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of Jason's and Karas's answer .

1. Bind with the corresponding properties between xaml and viewmodel .

   ```cs
   //xaml
   IsVisible = "{Binding IsVisible}"
   ```
2. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` inside viewmodel .

   ```cs
   public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


        private bool isVisible;
        public bool IsVisible { 
            get 
            {
                return isVisible;
            } 
            set 
            {
                isVisible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
   ```
3. Replace the event with [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior) and change the properties value.

   ```
   //xaml
    <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
                        EventName="MediaCaptured"
                        Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
   ```

   ```cs
   //viewmodel
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
        {
            MyCommand = new Command((obj)=> {
                var cameraView = obj as CameraView;
                switch (cameraView.CaptureMode)
                {
                    default:
                    case CameraCaptureMode.Default:
                    case CameraCaptureMode.Photo:
                        IsVisible = false;

                        break;
                    case CameraCaptureMode.Video:
                        IsVisible = false;
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First you create a BaseViewModel, which you can now inherit on every other ViewModel. Then your ViewModel and bind it via BindingContext = new YourPageVM() to your page via YourPage.cs. You can now create properties in your ViewModel and Binding them in the XAML. e.g .:
Here Is the BaseViewModel:

```
    public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string 
    propertyName = 
    "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new 
    PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
     
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
       [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
       Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    }

     //In Your VM:

     public class YourPageVM : BaseViewModel
     {
     bool isVisPreVideo;
     public bool IsVisPreVideo{ 
     get=> isVisPreVideo;
     set=> SetProperty(ref isVisPreVideo,value);}
    
     //set the Value in Constructor or in Your Method
     public YourPageVM()
     {
      IsVisPreVideo = false;
     }
     //........
     }
     //At Xaml:

     xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:YourProject.ViewModel" 
     x:DataType="viewmodel:YourPageVM"

     IsVisible = "{Binding IsVisPreVideo}"
```

And this you can do also with the other values Rotation, Source and Text.